# casting interface to T in c#

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting, theory

I have a piece of code that feels like this:(I've stripped the methods out because they don't help for this question)

```
public abstract class A { }
public interface I { }
public class C : A , I { }
public class Program
{
    static void Update<T>(List<T> l,A a,I i,C c)
    {

        l.Add((T)a);//Error
        l.Add((T)i);
        l.Add((T)c);//Error
    }
}
```

The casting fails at compile time for the abstract and the concrete class, but not the interface.

I know I could do something like `l.Add((T)(object)a);` to trick the compiler, but I don't understand why casting the interface to T works.(if they all went wrong then I could assume its some kind of type-check error)

I tried it in java, and they all work.

```
public static <T> void update(List<T> l,C c,I i,A a){
    l.add((T)c);//ok
    l.add((T)i);//ok
    l.add((T)a);//ok
}
```

Is it just because the way c# compiler is, or I am missing some concept on OOP?

Comment: How is update being called? What's T here?

Comment: What is T and where is the statement that calls Update<T>() method?

Comment: Is there any constraints, defined for T?

Comment: you are not putting the whole code. `A` doesnt implement `I` so you cant cast it.

Comment: So you call Update(someList, obj, obj, obj) where _obj_ is of type C?

Comment: Wait, how does this Java code even work? Isn't casting to generic parameter a no-op?

Comment: @Joker_vD This is not Java. This is C#. Only CLR, only Hardcore!

Comment: Anyhow, the very idea to have a generic and then do a manual cast..? Why, are runtime exceptions so much better than compilation errors?

Comment: thanks to all for the answers:) I probably should have said what I was doing first: I'm currently porting a codebase that has nearly 10 years of history from java to c#(about 100 classes). The specs were scarce, and the syntax and style was really old. I wanted to assure the c# code was as close to the java as possible, to make it build first.

Comment: @VMAtm the "public static <T> void update(List<T> l,C c,I i,A a)" is java, tried it in JDK1.6 inside a class. I shouldn't have stripped too much code ...

Comment: @SidharthMudgal the update function is a method from a database helper class. "Update" method updates the database using a parameter List<T> provided with a update condition helper interface along with an user authorization check abstract class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the compiler understand your code, you must constrain the `T` with keyword [`where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx), like this:

```
public abstract class A { }
public interface I { }
public class C : A, I { }
public class Program
{
    static void Update<T>(List<T> l, A a, I i, C c)
        // HERE IS THE CHANGE
        where T: C
    {

        l.Add((T)a);//Error
        l.Add((T)i);
        l.Add((T)c);//Error
    }
}
```

This is because `T` can be everything by default, even not class, and only after constrains all variants of the code will work.

You can compile this **only** if you constrain your method like I mention it, so the only use  you can do is:

```
var c = new C();
Update<C>(new List<C>(), c as A, (I)c, c);
```

This is **useless**, and you should rewrite your code. I think, you should use more interfaces, and less base classes.

Comment: `A` is abstract class which doenst implement `I`. how can u cast that to I?

Comment: @DarthVader a could be a subclass of A (in fact needs to be since A is abstract) and could additionally implement `I`

Comment: what if it is a class that doesnt implement `I` how would that be safe ?

Comment: @DarthVader it's still not safe- you can still get a Cast Exception at runtime, however it is safer.

Comment: In theory you could also have `D` which extends `C` and use `D` for `T` at the callsite.

Comment: In theory you shouldn't use such methods with mix of base abstract classes and interfaces.

Comment: I agree that the code is useless; the system that uses the code has been written by many people with different levels of skill(the first version of the codebase is about 10 years ago). The hierarchy is a nightmare, its like a full collection of thedailyWTF; I can't use the where keyword, it breaks some class library somewhere else in the code --- Yeah I need to convince the team to rewrite the code.

Answer (score 1):

At compile time it is unknown whether a class that implements interface `I` can actually be of type `T` and thus the compiler cannot complain. However `T` is unbound in your code and the compiler complains that `T` needs to have bounds declared to make the code safer.

You can workaround compile time safety and hope that all is going to work on the call site like so:

```
  l.Add((T)(object)a);// no compile time Error but possibly at runtime
  l.Add((T)i);  //no compile time Error but possibly at runtime
  l.Add((T)(object)c);// no compile time Error but possibly at runtime
```

But it would be a bad idea to sacrifice compile time checks.

Instead declare a bound for `T` for example like this:

```
static void Update<T>(List<T> l, A a, I i, C c)  where T: C {

  l.Add((T)a);// no compile time Error and less likely a runtime error
  l.Add((T)i);  //no compile time Error but still possibly at runtime
  l.Add((T)c);// no compile time Error and less likely a runtime error
}
```

It's easy to see how this could go wrong otherwise

If you call `Update<string>(stringlist, a, i, c)` - it would break otherwise because neither A, nor I, nor C can be cast to string.

Comment: `A` is abstract class which doenst implement `I`. how can u cast that to I?

Comment: @DarthVader `a` is an instance of a subclass of `A` (since `A` is abstract) and could additionally implement `I`- the compiler cannot know whether this will ever be the case, but it could be.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to cast arbitrary typed items to a generic type parameter in C#. Imagine there is an unrelated class `D` and you call `Update<D>(new List<D>(), new A(), new C())` - you will get an exception at run-time if you try to add an instance of `A` into a `List<D>`.

Consider a non-generic simpler implementation where you work with some interface `O`, rather than a generic parameter, e.g.:

```
public interface O { }
public interface I : O { }
public abstract class A : O { }
public class C : A, I { }

public class Program {
    static void Update(List<O> l, A a, I i, C c) {
        l.Add(a);
        l.Add(i);
        l.Add(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See 6.2.7 C# language specification ("Explicit conversions involving type parameters"), there's an explanation:

"

The following explicit conversions exist for a given type parameter T:

- *From any interface type to T*. At run-time, if T is a value type, the conversion is executed as an unboxing conversion. Otherwise, the conversion is executed as an explicit reference conversion or identity conversion.

*The above rules do not permit a direct explicit conversion from an unconstrained type parameter to a non-interface type*, which might be surprising. The reason for this rule is to prevent confusion and make the semantics of such conversions clear. For example, consider the following declaration:

```
class X<T>
{
   public static long F(T t) {
      return (long)t;            // Error 
   }
}
```

If the direct explicit conversion of t to int were permitted, one might easily expect that X.F(7) would return 7L. However, it would not, because the standard numeric conversions are only considered when the types are known to be numeric at binding-time.

"